# php image copy - черная полоса

Tags: php, gd

```
public function inSquare($widthHeight, $borders=0) {
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($widthHeight, $widthHeight);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($newImage, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefill($newImage, 0, 0, $white);

    imagecolortransparent($newImage, $white);

    $this->resize($widthHeight-($borders*2), $widthHeight-($borders*2));

    if($this->width > $this->height) { $left = $borders; $top = round(($widthHeight-$this->height)/2);}
    else {$left = round(($widthHeight-$this->width)/2); $top = $borders;}

    imagecopy($newImage, $this->image, $left, $top, 0, 0, $this->width, $this->height);

    $this->width = $widthHeight;
    $this->height = $widthHeight;
    $this->image = $newImage;

    return $this;
}
```

Данная функция оставляет черную полосу справа от исходного изображения. Почему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разобрался! стояло округление round в меньшую сторону при resize

Comment: какбэ, вы получили ответ немного ранее того, как разобрались. И было бы корректно оценить ответ и принять его. С уважением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте: `$left = ceil(($widthHeight-$this->width)/2);`

проверьте css (всяко ;))

попробуйте Imagick.